# ¿Cómo podría obtener el tamaño del disco en GB a un string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vb.net, vb, visual-basic

Estoy haciendo un programa de información del sistema y quiero mostrar la memoria del disco en GB, ya que he seguido un manual de StackOverflow pero me sale en bytes

```cs
int GetDiskSize(){
ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
disk.Get();
return (int)disk["Size"];
//No se puede convertir ManagementObject a int
//Si hago .ToString(); me sale en bytes
}
```

Resultado: [image: 479.310.376.960]

```
GB  MB  KB  B
479.310.376.960
```

me sale en bytes

Tambien me sale 0GB
[image: 0GB (unknown)]
y debería salir 446GB pero no se como convertirlo a GB desde Bytes con C# y dNF no incluye ningún `void()` ni `string()` o `int()` que lo haga

`dNF es dotNet Framework`
Fuente: [stackoverflow: using c# how can i extract information about...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232979/using-c-sharp-how-can-i-extract-information-about-the-hard-drives-present-on-the#:%7E:text=ManagementObject%20disk%20%3D%20new%20ManagementObject%20%28%22win32_logicaldisk.deviceid%3D%22c%3A%22%22%29%3B%20disk.Get%20%28%29%3B,FreeSpace%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20disk%20%5B%22FreeSpace%22%5D%20%2B%20%22bytes%22%29%3B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk) dice que `Size` es un entero sin signo de 64 bits con la cantidad de *bytes* del disco.

En C# `int` es un entero con signo de 32 bits. `ulong` sí tiene las características necesarias.

Entonces:

- Convierte el valor a `ulong`.
- Aplica un factor de conversión a la unidad deseada. Para GB sería 1 / 10<sup>9</sup>.

```
ulong GetDiskSize(){
    ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
    disk.Get();
    return (ulong)disk["Size"];
}

int gb = (int)(GetDiskSize() / 1000000000);
```

Comment: gracias por ayudarme, lo he aplicado y ya me devuelve la cantidad en GB

Comment: ¿Dividiendo por 1000000000 no se obtienen más gigas de la cuenta?

Comment: @RubioRic no. 1 GB = 10⁹ bytes. 1 GiB = 2³⁰ bytes. Lo que sucede es que Windows nos engañó a todos porque usa múltiplos binarios pero usa el prefijo sin la **i** al medio. Yussef lo explica en su respuesta.

Comment: Justo. Dependiendo de lo que quieras obtener deberías emplear un divisor u otro. OP indicó en la pregunta original que esperaba 446 (Segundo ejemplo de Yussef)

Comment: @Rubio considero que así está bien. El código es un mero ejemplo, solo tiene que usar un factor diferente para la unidad en que quiera expresarlo.

Answer (score 4):

Kilo, mega, giga, tera, peta, etc son solo prefijos que indican una cantidad (o un factor) con respecto a la unidad. Es decir, Un kilo de bytes quiere decir mil bytes, y así un giga de bytes (1GB) son 1.000.000.000 de bytes. Por lo que para convertir `4.793.310.376.960` en GB solo debes dividir

```
 479.310.376.960
-----------------   = 479GB (aprox)
  1.000.000.000
```

Ahora bien, si bien esto de los prefijos es cierto para todos los campos de las ciencias de la ingeniería, en la computación hubo un problema, por un asunto práctico relacionado con la aritmética binaria se tomó la decisión que un kilo fuera 1.024 (2<sup>10</sup>) y si bien esto fue resuelto por [ISO/IEC 80000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000)  hace ya bastante años, creando otra unidad llamada `bibyte`, aun al día de hoy se mezclan los conceptos provocando que uno no sepa cual es el factor que se está usando. En tu caso, dado que tu resultado esperado es 446, lo "correcto" sería hablar de `gibibyte` en lugar de `gigabyte`

| Sistema internacional de medidas | múltiplo | ISO/IEC 80000 | múltiplo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| kilobyte (kB) | 10<sup>3</sup> | kibibyte (KiB) | 2<sup>10</sup> |
| megabyte (MB) | 10<sup>6</sup> | mebibyte (MiB) | 2<sup>20</sup> |
| gigabyte (GB) | 10<sup>9</sup> | gibibyte (GiB) | 2<sup>30</sup> |
| terabyte (TB) | 10<sup>12</sup> | tebibyte (TiB) | 2<sup>40</sup> |
| petabyte (PB) | 10<sup>15</sup> | pebibyte (PiB) | 2<sup>50</sup> |

Ahora considera que 2<sup>30</sup> = 1.073.741.824, tienes que

```
 479.310.376.960
-----------------   = 446 GiB
  1.073.741.824
```

En otras palabras, solo divide el número por `1.073.741.824`

Comment: Al hacer `int x = (int)disk["Size"];` me devuelve La conversion especificada no es valida                He hecho un string() con este código: ` ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
disk.Get();
int x = (int)disk["Size"];
int y = 1073741824;
int z = x / y;
return z.ToString();` pero el (int)disk["Size"] no funciona así